# Error in data$Y_i1: object of type 'closure' is not sub settable

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a dataset with 46 observations and three variables called data. I'm literally just running an ATE and I'm getting the above error message when knitting. It runs in the `rmd`. Here is my code, can someone help. Please avoid the advanced r jargon, I'm new to this.

```
ATE <- mean(data$Y_i1) - mean(data$Y_i0)
ATE ## Average Treatment Effect
```

```
N <- 23 # Half of observations
var1 <- var(data$Y_i1)
var0 <- var(data$Y_i0)
var1N <- var1/N
var0N <- var0/N
SEATE <- sqrt(var1N + var0N)
SEATE ## The Standard Error of the ATE
```

Getting the errors for essentially every line with $.

[image]

Comment: it doesnt knit!!!

Comment: I'm sorry can you elaborate?

Comment: For example, if you have named blocks with the same name, it could happen i.e. ```{r name1}`. In the image showed, I didn't find any case like that.  The example works fine for me

Comment: When knitting markdown it acts as if your environment does not have variables and starts reading data only from your script. Make sure you include the import/read statement of data in your rmd file. Probably you read data without including import in rmd file and now R is trying to check its built in data function because it does not understand what data is.

Comment: Where did you define the `data` variable? It sounds like you haven't defined one and R is trying to subset the built-in data function. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.